# Deploy SSIS Project using TFS Command Line

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssis, sql-server-2016, devops

How do I deploy an SSIS project from TFS 2015?

For regular database projects, it is `sqlpackage.exe /publish`  with publish profile.

What is the command line argument to auto deploy SSIS Project Model into a server?

We are using SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why using [runas command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))??

> Runas command allows a user to run specific tools and programs with different permissions than the user's current logon provides.

Based on [Deploy an SSIS project from the command prompt with ISDeploymentWizard.exe:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-cmdline?view=sql-server-2017#wizard_auth):

> If you're deploying to a SQL Server with the Deployment Wizard, you have to use Windows authentication; you can't use SQL Server authentication.

Then if the current user has access to the remote server you don't need to use runas command then no need to provide a password.

---

### How to use IsDeploymentWizard to automate ssis project (.ispac) deployment?

First of all, run `ISDeploymentWizard.exe /?` from a command prompt, and you’ll see the full list of arguments it supports with their abbreviations.

[image]

You only have to use `IsDeploymentWizard` in silent mode to prevent showing the wizard, but you should specify the argument needed.

```
ISDeploymentWizard /S /SP:foo.ispac /DS:myserver /DP:/ssisdb/test/test
```

A shortcut to building the initial arguments for the ISDeploymentWizard is provided by the GUI version of the program. In the confirmation screen, you would see an image like the following

[image: Confirmation screen]

Note the Command Line section - those are the arguments you will need to pass for an automated deployment (Ctrl-C will copy that entire line if you select it)

#### References & Helpful Links

- [Project & Package Deployment Methods – SSIS Basics](https://camneale.wordpress.com/tag/isdeploymentwizard/)
- [Can I Automate SSIS Project Deployment?](https://www.mattmasson.com/2013/05/can-i-automate-ssis-project-deployment/)
- [ISDeploymentWizard switch](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec1711fd-2677-4330-9b8d-7f79e8a25747/isdeploymentwizard-switch?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [dtutil Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility?view=sql-server-2017) *(single package deployment tool)*
- [SSIS Build & Deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS)

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425684/deploy-ssas-project-using-tfs-command-line

Comment: @billinkc can you have a look on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044181/ssis-deployment-command-in-cmd-doesnt-print-any-indication-for-status