# Deploy SSAS Project using TFS Command Line

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssas, sql-server-2016, devops

How do I deploy an SSAS Cube project from TFS 2015?

For regular database projects, it is `sqlpackage.exe /publish`  with publish profile.

What is the command line argument to auto deploy SSAS Project Model into a server?

We are currently using SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe`  located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio
```

*Syntax*

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment [ASdatabasefile]    
{[/s[:logfile]] | [/a] | [[/o[:output_script_file]] [/d]]}
```

Make sure to use `/s` to run in silent mode to prevent opening the wizard:

For more information about the arguments check the following article:

- [Deploy Model Solutions with the Deployment Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/deploy-model-solutions-with-the-deployment-utility?view=sql-server-2016)

**References**

- [Running the Analysis Services Deployment Wizard at the Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/running-the-analysis-services-deployment-wizard?view=sql-server-2016#running-the-analysis-services-deployment-wizard-at-the-command-prompt)
- [Deploy Model Solutions with the Deployment Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/deploy-model-solutions-with-the-deployment-utility?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: I think this answer is the second half of the solution. The first half is automating the build of the project to generate the new .asdatabase file. http://www.blue-granite.com/blog/applying-configurations-tabular-model-ms-build

Comment: @GregGalloway thanks for sharing this article. But the OP didn't mentioned that. he is looking to a command line similar to `sqlpackage.exe /publish` which is used to deploy ssdt database project

Comment: Got it. So he wants to publish a stale .asdatabase file. Makes complete sense.