# ISDeploymentWizard.exe command (SSIS deployment ) in CMD doesn't print any indication for status

Tags: cmd, ssis, ssms

I'm running the below command in `CMD` for `SSIS`:

```
ISDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:"C:\TEST\Integration Services.ispac" /DestinationServer:"TEST03,1111" /DestinationPath:"/TEST/DEVOPS"
```

and it finished successfully but with no indication to the command line. I can only check with `SSMS` to make sure it was really deployed. any idea why?

Comment: `/Silent` looks to me like an obvious clue as to why there was no indication. How to use `SSMS` is not a valid on topic question for StackOverflow.

Comment: as per my understating, `/Silent` means its running in background with default options. It has nothing to do with the outcome result.

Comment: No clue on the downvote to the self-answer there but I concur with what you found from the MSDN link. Not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solid observation here @areilma - the /silent option eliminates all status info. I had always assumed that flag controlled whether the gui was displayed or not.

If I run this command

```
isdeploymentwizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:".\SO_66497856.ispac" /DestinationServer:".\dev2017" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/BatchSizeTester/SO_66497856"
```

My package is deployed to my local machine at the path specified. Removing the /silent option causes the GUI to open up with the prepopulated values.

```
isdeploymentwizard.exe  /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:".\SO_66497856.ispac" /DestinationServer:".\dev2017" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/BatchSizeTester/SO_66497856"
```

When the former command runs, nothing is printed to the command prompt. So that's happy path deployment, maybe if something is "wrong", I'd get an error message on the command line. And this is where things got "interesting".

I altered my destination path to a folder that doesn't exist. I know the tool doesn't create a path if it doesn't exist and when I ran it, I didn't get an error back on the command line. What I did get, was a pop up windowed error of

> TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services

> The path does not exist. The folder 'cBatchSizeTester' was not found in catalog 'SSISDB'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common)

> BUTTONS:

> OK

So the /silent option removes the gui to allow us to have an automated deploy but if a bad value is passed, we return to having a gui... I then repeated with a bad server name, which led to a second observation. The second I hit enter, the command line returned ready for the next command. 15 seconds later however,

> TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services

> Failed to connect to server .\dev2017a. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Well now, that tells me that the actual deployment is an independent spawned process. So it won't return any data back to the command line, in any case.

Since I assume we're looking at this from a CI/CD perspective, what can we do? We could fire off a `sqlcmd` afterwards looking for an entry in the SSISDB catalog views to see what happened. Something like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 O.end_time, SV.StatusValue, F.name AS FolderName, P.name AS ProjectName FROM catalog.operations AS O 
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT
    CASE O.status
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Created'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Running'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Pending'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Ended unexpectedly'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Stopping'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Completed'
    END AS StatusValue
)SV
INNER JOIN catalog.object_versions AS OV ON OV.object_id = O.object_id
INNER JOIN catalog.projects AS P ON P.object_version_lsn = OV.object_version_lsn
INNER JOIN catalog.folders AS F ON F.folder_id = P.folder_id
/*
    INNER JOIN
        catalog.packages AS PKG
        ON PKG.project_id = P.project_id
*/
WHERE O.operation_type = 101 /*deploy project*/
AND P.name = 'SO_66497856' /*project name*/
AND F.name = 'BatchSizeTester'
ORDER BY o.created_time DESC
```

Perhaps a filter against end_time of within the past 10 seconds would be appropriate and if we have a result and the status is Succeeded we got a deploy. No result means it failed. I presume something similar happens when the gui runs and despite all this testing, I'm not interested in firing up a trace to fully round out this answer and see what happens behind the scenes.

If you want to negate the value of the prebuilt tool, the other option would be to use the ManagedObjectModel/PowerShell approach to deploy as you can get info from there. The other deployment option is with the TSQL Commands. The second link in my documentation section outlines what that would look like

### Paltry documentation I could find

I could find no documentation as to the command line switches for `isdeploymentwizard.exe`

- [Deploy an SSIS project from the command prompt with ISDeploymentWizard.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-cmdline?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15)
- From @arielma's deleted answer, they found a more succinct answer saying "[not possible](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec1711fd-2677-4330-9b8d-7f79e8a25747/isdeploymentwizard-switch)"

Comment: One more documentation I've found: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec1711fd-2677-4330-9b8d-7f79e8a25747/isdeploymentwizard-switch

Comment: I posted question which is related to this issue... can you have a look as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604718/how-to-have-ssis-exception-in-my-console-log

Comment: Agree that isdeploymentwizard.exe is kind of a dead end.  I went with PowerShell option in the end.